# Why is the ToC missing in org-mode LaTeX output?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

With the following `book.org`

```
#+title: My Title
#+author: My Name

#+LATEX_CLASS: memoir
#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [oneside]
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[mag=2000, truedimen]{geometry}

#+INCLUDE: "chap1.org"
#+INCLUDE: "chap2.org"
```

and with both `chap1.org` and `chap2.org` having

```
* Chapter Title
Lorem Ipsum
```

I get an empty table of contents following
<kbd>C-c</kbd>
<kbd>C-e</kbd>
<kbd>l</kbd>
<kbd>o</kbd>.

Normally one needs to run LaTeX twice (to get an `.aux` file) before a ToC appears. Yet even after a second run the ToC is missing. Why?

[image: ToC is missing]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Run Twice

One solution is to configure `org-latex-pdf-process` to run LaTeX *twice*.

```
(setq org-latex-pdf-process
      '("pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
        "pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"))
```

[image: ToC appears when LaTeX runs twice]

This of course comes at the price of twice-as-slow LaTeX runs.

A better solution (for future work) would be to prevent the `.aux` file from being deleted, and accept that the ToC may be slightly off.

##### latexmk

Credit for this solution goes to NickD.

Another solution is to use `latexmk`.

```
(setq org-latex-pdf-process
      '("latexmk -shell-escape -f -pdf %f"))
```

[`latexmk`](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk) will generate a correct ToC after one run. You may already have `latexmk`, as it is included in both MacTeX and MikTeX.

Oddly, `latexmk` is slower (by 30%) than two runs of `pdflatex`.

Comment: What version of Org mode are you using? The current version uses `latexmk` in `org-latex-pdf-process` (assuming you have `latexmk` installed of course): that takes care of multiple runs, bibtex/biblatex and other such tasks so you don't have to worry about it. I highly recommend that you install `latexmk` and that you use it in `org-latex-pdf-process`, instead of running multiple `pdflatex'`s. I also recommend that you use `xelatex` or `lualatex`, rather than `pdflatex`: they are much better in dealing with Unicode.

Comment: You should be able to install [latexmk](https://personal.psu.edu/jcc8/software/latexmk-jcc/) with your distro's installation method: e.g. on Fedora 37, I just did `sudo dnf install latexmk`.

Comment: @NickD Nice, but if speed is what ultimately matters for frequent previews, two runs of `pdflatex` are still better. (I'm running Org-mode v. 9.5.5.)

Comment: BTW, the default was *three* invocations of `pdflatex`, because that was the worst case scenario known (although ISTR horror stories about a pathological case that wouldn't converge no matter what...) The default was changed to `latexmk` in commit [32739e35e3da37ea8eddaf8c65abc5c1b442a2e5](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/commit/?id=32739e35e3da37ea8eddaf8c65abc5c1b442a2e5)

Comment: Actually, the default depends on whether `latexmk` is found: it's the default if present, but if you don't have it installed, then it falls back to three invocations of `pdflatex`.